# How to initialize phonegap speech to text plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, text, initialization, speech

I'm developing a phonegap application.

Download plugin and connect button with javascript function, but it doesn't work..

**"Error: exec proxy not found for :: SpeechRecognition :: isRecognitionAvailable"**

I think this error cause "not initialized plugin". Right?

How to initialize Speech Recognization plugin??

Comment: How did you try ??

Comment: @Naresh Kumar I'm still resolving...
I send you link : https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer
good luck..ㅠㅠ